# Reaching the element in json with stream() in Java 8

Tags: java, json, java-stream

I was working on my project, then I need the reach an element in the Json Data Look like:

```
[
  {
    "name": "Meltem",
    "items": [
      {
        "name": "Yilmaz",
        "histories": [
          {
            "date": 1615370705561,
            "school": "BAU"
          }
        ]
       }
     ]
   }
]
```

So I can reach the element of name with:

```
var myData = data().
                stream().
                filter(x -> x.getName().equals("Meltem"))
                .collect(Collectors.toList())
                .get(0);
```

So, how to reach the **school** with using stream() in java 8?

Also, the `getName()` where I called;

```
@Getter
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonPropertyOrder({
        "name",
        "items",
})
public class Package {
@JsonProperty("name")
    private String name;
@JsonProperty("items")
    private List<Item> items;
}
```

Comment: you cannot name a variable "package"

Comment: I the entire json already parsed and stored in data

Comment: Also you seam to have some kind of holder class. Could you provide the class where you called .getName() on

Comment: yes @IntoVoid it is

Comment: What is the exact type of data?

Comment: And how did you convert the json into your data structure (Did you use JSONObject or something)

Comment: I edited my question @IntoVoid I don't use JSONObject

Answer (score 4):

`flatMap` is your friend:

```java
var mySchool = data().
    stream()
    .filter(x -> x.getName().equals("Meltem"))
    .flatMap(x->x.getItems().stream())
    .flatMap(item->item.getHistories().stream())
    .map(history->history.getSchool())
    .collect(Collectors.toList())
    .get(0);
```

`flatMap()` takes each element in the stream and maps each element to a Stream according to the operation you tell it to run. Then, it creates a Stream that containing all elements of each stream loaded previously.

The code I provided gets you a `List` with all schools in all histories in all items in all packages with the name `MeItem`.

If you just want to get the first element, I would use `Stream#findFirst` without converting it to a `List`:

```java
var mySchool = data().
    stream()
    .filter(x -> x.getName().equals("Meltem"))
    .flatMap(x->x.getItems().stream())
    .flatMap(item->item.getHistories().stream())
    .map(history->history.getSchool())
    .findFirst()
    .orElse(null);//or use the Optional for whatever you want
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
var myData = data.stream()
                     .filter(x -> x.getName().equals("Meltem"))
                     .flatMap(x -> x.getItems().stream())
                     .filter(x -> x.getName().equals("Yilmaz"))
                     .flatMap(x -> x.getHistories().stream())
                     .map(History::getSchool)
                     .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Assuming your classes look something like this:

```
public static class Package {
    private String name;
    private List<Item> items;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public List<Item> getItems() {
        return items;
    }
}

public static class Item {
    private String name;
    private List<History> histories;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public List<History> getHistories() {
        return histories;
    }
}

public static class History {
    private String school;

    public String getSchool() {
        return school;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var myData = data().
            stream().
            filter(x -> x.getName().equals("Meltem"))
            .collect(Collectors.toList())
            .get(0).getHistories().get(0).getSchool();
```

Won't it work for you?